# Lambda statement Intersect

Tags: c#, lambda, intersect

Trying to work out this lambda query without doing a foreach etc. I currently have a database table with a column which contains a comma separated list of strings. It's basically a filter (it could for example be 'pants,tops,t-shirts,gloves'). In the function that queries the database is basically has a parameter that accepts a similar string.

I don't know if I'm just too tired at the moment and can't work it out but struggling. I know it will be Intersect but can't figure out the syntax.

Currently I have...

```
    public static List<ItemListItem> GetItems(string filter = "")
    {
        var db = new dbConnection();

        var results = (from i in db.Items
                       select i);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (filter))
            results = results.Where(x => x.Filters.Split(',').Intersect(filter.Split(',')) )

    }
```

Comment: I think all you need is to return `.Count() > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Enumerable.Any` at the end of your `Intersect` like:

```
x.Filters.Split(',').Intersect(filter.Split(',')).Any()
```

So your query would be:

```
results = results.Where(x => x.Filters.Split(',')
    .Intersect(filter.Split(','))
    .Any());
```

`Enumerable.Where` would require an expression returning `bool`. `Intersect` would return an `IEnumerable<T>` and `Enumerable.Where` would not accept it. Adding `Enumerable.Any` would means return those rows where intersection resulted in *Any* row.